# How to get all features returned when zoomed out with mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using mapbox gl js.   I want to get a list of all sport facilities in the map being viewed.  When close up the below works, however, when zoomed out it doesn't return all the data.  I would assume this is to do with tilesets and what is rendered at each zoom.  How would I go about getting all sports facilities and zoomed way out please?  Below unfortunately will not work.

```
     const featuresRendered = map.queryRenderedFeatures(
         {
             layers: ['aa_winter_spoorts_points']
         }
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [enter link description here](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/tilequery/)TileQuery API.  You can specify a center point and a distance, and it will return all features of a given type in that area.